# Unknown 'like' in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like

My database:

```
+------------+
| Number     |
+------------+
| 8883277777 |
+------------+
| 8883555354 |
+------------+
| 8181888867 |
+------------+
| 8881143185 |
+------------+
```

When we do:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE Number LIKE "88%"
```

It will result:

> 8883277777, 8883555354, 8881143185
>
> ---

When we do:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE Number LIKE "%88%"
```

It will result:

> 8181888867
>
> ---

When we do:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE Number LIKE "%77%"
```

It will result:

> 8883277777
>
> ---

---

What should be the query for fetching ***%yyyy%***?

*Where y = any number (0/1/2/3/4/5/6/8/9).*

The result will be:

> **8883277777, 8181888867**

Comment: Don't you have a question to go with all this ? Are you just saying ? :P

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're after regex, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    numbers
WHERE
    Number REGEXP '(0{4}|1{4}|2{4}|3{4}|4{4}|5{4}|6{4}|7{4}|8{4}|9{4})'
```

Is that what are you looking for?

Comment: Somehow same +1, then what will be the query for ***%yyyy***, the result will be `8883277777`

Answer (score 2):

You could try using OR

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM numbers 
    WHERE Number LIKE "%0000%"
    OR Number LIKE "%1111%"
    OR Number LIKE "%2222%"
    OR Number LIKE "%3333%"
    OR Number LIKE "%4444%"
    OR Number LIKE "%5555%"
    OR Number LIKE "%6666%"
    OR Number LIKE "%7777%"
    OR Number LIKE "%8888%"     
    OR Number LIKE "%9999%"
```

Comment: Which one is better using `OR` ***or*** using `regex`? +1 for the right answer